# Unable to create test Runner class in Cucumber Framework due to Error in resolving Cucumber Options

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am working on creating a Cucumber Framework for Test Automation. Issue I am facing is I am not able to resolve the imports for CucumberOptions in the Test Runner class

Initially I tried to use the Suggestion of importing cucumber.api which is now deprecated. Then I went to the official Cucumber site to find the imports but they are not solving the problem as well.

Deprecated Import :

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
```

Import from Cucumber Official Site :

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
```

After adding the above import I am facing the error :

```
The import io.cucumber.junit cannot be resolved
```

Below is the code in the Test Runner class :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(features = {"Features"}, glue= {"stepDefinitions"}, dryRun=true)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Below is the POM Structure with all the dependencies :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>CucumberFramework</groupId>
  <artifactId>CucumberFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>AmazonCucumberFramework</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency> 
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cobertura/cobertura -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cobertura</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

I would like to know if there are any new dependencies that need to be added. I remember working on cucumber earlier before cucumber.api was deprecated and it used to work fine.

Comment: Did you run `mvn clean install` from the cli?

Comment: Yes I did. But that did not solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try `mvn clean` and then `mvn install -U` on the terminal, at this time you don't use the IDE to make sure the problem isn't in the IDE, use the terminal.

Example `pom.xml`: https://github.com/osvaldjr/easy-cucumber/blob/master/pom.xml

Import: `cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-spring`